# TypeError: Operator >= not compatible with types bytes1 and int_const 37

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

library EmailRegex {
  struct State {
    bool accepts;
    function (byte) internal pure returns (uint) func;
  }

  function state(uint id) internal pure returns (State memory) {
    if (id == 1) {
      return State(false, s1);
    }
    if (id == 2) {
      return State(false, s2);
    }
}
function matches(string memory input) public pure returns (bool) {
    uint cur = 1;

    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes(input).length; i++) {
      bytes1 c = bytes(input)[i];

      cur = state(cur).func(c);
      if (cur == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return state(cur).accepts;
  }

  function s1(byte c) internal pure returns (uint) {
    if (c >= 37 && c <= 37 || c >= 43 && c <= 43 || c >= 45 && c <= 45 || c >= 46 && c <= 46 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 95 && c <= 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 2;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function s2(byte c)  internal pure  returns (uint) {
    if (c >= 37 && c <= 37 || c >= 43 && c <= 43 || c >= 45 && c <= 45 || c >= 46 && c <= 46 || c >= 48 && c <= 57 || c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 95 && c <= 95 || c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      return 3;
    }
    if (c >= 64 && c <= 64) {
      return 4;
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Trying to have a test run from source code from GitHub and faced this error. At first, it came with *pragma solidity ^0.4.26* version then I changed it to *pragma solidity ^0.5.16*.

I am not sure of how can I replace the operator error.
Here is the **error log**

https://github.com/lionel1702/log/blob/master/emailRegexLog

Comment: Replace `byte` with `uint8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few solutions for this:

- If `c` needs to be a `byte`, you can use hexadecimal notation, e.g. `c >= 0x25 && c <= 0x25` (or `c == 0x25`).
- Otherwise, you can simply cast the type from `byte` to `uint8` (which is essentially the same type, since both consist of 8 bits):

  ```
  uint8 c = uint8(bytes(input)[i]);

  // ...
  function s1(uint8 c) internal pure returns (uint) { ... }
  ```

Note that `c == 37` is the same as `c >= 37 && c <= 37`, so you can simplify your functions like this:

```
function s1(uint8 c) internal pure returns (uint) {
  if (c == 37 || c == 43 || c == 45 || c == 46 || ...) {
    return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/lionel1702/log/blob/master/emailRegexLog2

i ran "truffle.cmd test" now the error is at the return `return State(false, **s1**);`
error at the s1

Comment: Make sure you update `c` variable in your `matches` function to explicitly `uint8` explicitly.

Comment: `function matches(string memory input) public pure returns (bool) {
    uint cur = 1;

    for (uint i = 0; i < bytes(input).length; i++) {
      bytes1 c = bytes(input)[i];

      cur = state(cur).func(uint8 c);
      if (cur == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return state(cur).accepts;
  }`

Like this?

Comment: Change `bytes1 c = bytes(input)[i];` to `uint8 c = uint8(bytes(input)[i]);`.